# PHPExcel additional text add to column

Tags: php, phpexcel

I have PHPExcel plugin to generated excel which data came from database, how if I wanted to add in additional text into a column A during the loop, and column B remain untouched data as from DB?

For example column A in DB is

`alex`

`andy`

`jennifer`

when output to excel, I wanted to add `@domain.com` for each name behind, wich will become

`alex@domain.com`

`andy@domain.com`

`jennifer@domain.com`

**Code:**

```
$query = "SELECT mail_name, account_id FROM email ORDER BY mail_name ASC";
$headings = array('Email', 'Id');

if ($result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error())) {
// Create a new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('emailList');


$rowNumber = 1;
$col = 'A';
foreach($headings as $heading) {
   $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$heading);
   $col++;
}

// Loop through the result set
$rowNumber = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $col = 'A';
    foreach($row as $cell) {
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue($col.$rowNumber,$cell);
        $col++;
    }
    $rowNumber++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that $col++ is not going to work.

What about this way?:

```
// Loop through the result set
$rowNumber = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber,$row['mail_name'].'@domain.com');
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                ->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber,$row['account_id']);
    ++$rowNumber;
}
```

Comment: not working, `Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by...`

Comment: This error doesn't have anything to do with your question (niether my answer). Check at the top of your file that there are no blank spaces before the <?php tag.